# YAML::TypedBadConversion<int> when running execution file

Tags: cmake, yaml

We're making a game as a project for class and using YAML when I ran into the following error:

Error:

```
Error: bad file: atb/window/window.yaml
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YAML::TypedBadConversion<int>'
     what(): bad conversion
```

In window.yaml:

```
"title": "Crossy Road"
"width": 1200
"height": 680

"interface-list": 
  -
    "file": "test.yaml" 
    "x": 0
    "y": 0
    "w": 100 
    "h": 100 

"choose-interface": "test"

"control":
  -
    "key": ["alt", "f4"]
    "action": "shutdown"
  - 
    "key": ["ctrl", "p"]
    "action": "pause"
  - 
    "key": ["s"]
    "action": "setting"
```

Additional info: (please kindly tell me to provide more if anything's missing)
OS: Windows 11
g++ version: 13.1.0
IDE: Visual Studio Code
Cmake: 3.28.0, generator: Ninja

I tried asking ChatGPT and also looked at other entries on our forum, both attempts suggest there's some sort of syntax error in my file. I tried running it through online YAML parsers and all said my file is fine. This is my first time using YAML and I didn't know where else to look, so I'll be really grateful if someone can give me some more pointers. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The error message (exception) is about your **code** which reads given YAML file. Without looking into the code we cannot help you in fixing it. When post a code, make sure to point to the line which causes given exception.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Hi, can you give me a few examples where that code may be? Any common file names perhaps? Thank you.

Comment: Examples of code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71541084/getting-yamltypedbadconversion-when-trying-to-read-string-value-with-yaml-cpp, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916672/getting-error-yamltypedbadconversiondouble. You could easily find more examples by searching for the error message or its parts.